# Draw boundary on colormap in Gnuplot using second data file

Tags: gnuplot, overlay, contour, colormap

I have an ASCII data file (density.dat) in the format (x y D), where D represents a density-value at the point (x,y), from which I create a colormap:

```
   set pm3d interpolate 2,2 corners2color mean
   set view map
   splot data_file u (1e9*$1):(1e9*$2):3 with pm3d
```

I have a second data file (potential.dat) with the same format (x y P), where P represents a potential value which can only have one of two values zero or 1.0 (say). I would like to indicate the boundary between the (three) regions (a straight line with slight perturbations) where the potential is zero and the regions where it is non-zero and overlay it on the first colormap of the density.

I though the approach where I plot the contours from one file on the plot of another file (similar to [here](http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.co.at/search?q=contour)), could work but the exported data using the 'set table filename' cannot be used for 'plot filename with image' it seems.

I would greatly appreciate ideas (or solutions..) to tackle this problem.

======== EDIT ==========
Working solution for me:

```
    set contour base
    set cntrparam level discrete 1.0

    splot density_file u 1:2:3 with pm3d nocontour,\
          potential_file u 1:2:3 w l nosurface
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the link you give, `with image` is used to plot the colour map, not the isolines, these are plotted `with lines`. I am not sure why you need to go through a table at all, it seems that you can handle everything with `splot` commands, unless you want to make fancy customisations or have strong constraints with margin control. See the discussion at the top of the post 
http://gnuplot-tricks.blogspot.co.uk/2009/07/maps-contour-plots-with-labels.html

You will need to give more details in your post if you want a more precise answer.

Comment: That was also my first attempt. Initially it did not work, which turned out  was just due to a typo (as is mostly the case in my gnuplot scripts...). 
It works fine now - thanks for the input.